# **Determine parameters p and q so that this quotient is a remarkable quotient**

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**I have tried to find the values of p and q so that this is a remarkable quotient, but I arrive at a quadratic diophanic equation.
Is there a shortcut?**

$$\dfrac{m^{4p+3q-2} - n^{6p+2q}}{m^{q} -n ^{p-1}}$$

**edited what is in bold**

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You must put `$` signs around MathJax command in order for them to be effective.  If you want display style, as above, use `$$` signs.  MathJax will take care of the indentation.  Don't indent yourself; it messes things up.  

On to the question.  What is a "diopthanum"?  What do you mean by the values of $p$ and $q$?  What conditions should they satisfy?

Comment: What is a remarkable quotient?

Comment: @ Ross Millikan,is one that has remainder  0,.for example  $(x ^ 3-y ^ 3) / (x-y)$